# Why is the filelist array null in Java with Android Studio?

Tags: android, java-io

I am using Android Studio with Java.

I have written a method (namely deleteWithExtension) to delete files from device internal memory. This method is adding some test files and tries to get the listof these files.

But the problem is that, the code never goes in the for-loop because of the array theFiles[] returns null. As you can see that, the code begins with sample files adding process so it should not be empty. I can also see those sample files in the Device File Explorer of Android Studio.

```
public static void CreateFile(Context mContext, String fileName, String textToBeWritten) {
    try {
        File dosya = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + fileName);
        dosya.createNewFile();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dosya);
        BufferedWriter yazici = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        yazici.write(textToBeWritten);
        yazici.flush();
        yazici.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void deleteWithExtension(Context mContext, String extension) {
    //First let's add a few sample files with same extension.
    CreateFile(mContext,"SampleFile1.smp","anything1");
    CreateFile(mContext,"SampleFile2.smp","anything2");
    CreateFile(mContext,"SampleFile3.smp","anything3");
    CreateFile(mContext,"SampleFile4.smp","anything4");
    CreateFile(mContext,"SampleFile5.smp","anything5");

    //Now, 5 sample files have been added. Let get them and put in an array.
    File dir = mContext.getFilesDir();
    final String[] theFiles = dir.list();
    for (final String file : theFiles) {    
        //do something here....
        int aa=9;
        //The code never goes into here, because array theFiles is always null but 5 sample files was added at first.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the CreateFile() method as follows. I hope I can help you.

```
public static void CreateFile(Context mContext, String fileName, String textToBeWritten) {
        try {
            File dosya = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + File.separator + fileName);
            dosya.createNewFile();
    
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dosya);
            BufferedWriter yazici = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            yazici.write(textToBeWritten);
            yazici.flush();
            yazici.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me much indeed. This solved my problem.